# recursive function returns string

Tags: c

I ran out of ideas. I only used to deal with integers for recursive functions,
so the program output should be:

```
Please enter a number : 4 
a
ab
abc
abcd 
abc 
ab
a
```

by far this is the only thing I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char arr [] ;
char*arr function(int count){
   char ch='a';
  if(count==1||count==count) 
     return ch;
  return (ch +function(count--)); 
 }//end method

main (){
  function(4);
 }//end main
```

Comment: `if(count==1||count==count)` doesnt make any sense since `count==count` will always be true. Also your function says your returning a `char*` but `return ch;` says your returning a `char`. Also `return (ch +function(count--));` your trying to add two `char` values which in C will give you the value of the integer encoding (I believe ASCII) of each char added together which isnt what you want

Comment: Is recursion really the best way to accomplish that output?

Comment: Consider that a C string is just a pointer to an array of `char`.  The end of the *string* is designated by a zero byte, but that doesn't have to be at the actual end of the array.  Consider allocating a large enough working array, and having your recursive function modify and print the contents in-place.

Comment: http://ideone.com/W7SY7h

Comment: Do you really need to return anything? It sounds like you just need to produce some output.

Answer (score 0):

Since strings are character arrays/pointers in C (with a "`NUL` char marks end" convention), the way to get the expected recursive behaviour of "strings as values" is to wrap a character array in a struct. Like this:

```
struct MyString {
    char s[10];
};
```

Now you would do something like:

```
struct MyString f(int count, int index)
{
    struct MyString result;
    rslt.s[0] = 'a' + index;
    rslt.s[1] = '\0';
    if (count == 1) {
        return result;
    }
    strcat(result.s, f(--count, ++index).s);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    f(4, 0);
}
```

I haven't tried to solve your programming problem here, just illustrating how to deal with strings as values in recursive functions. It works the same way for function arguments, not just results.